# HTML5 based Document(doc/xls) Viewer & Editor : What are my options?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, ms-word, wysiwyg, google-docs

I am intended to build an HTML5 based document editor with features like google docs, the documents are word documents and excel documents stored in server. Backend uses asp.net MVC.

I've found some ways to support doc file editing, but couldn't find any solution for xls.

Is there any good strategy or solution to do this?
Is it feasible as a solo project or it's too ambitious?

If anyone could give some directions,
Any suggestions or guidelines would help.

Comment: Do you want to create something similar to google docs? B-)

Comment: yes I want to create something where I upload documents and I can edit them online and this will be achieved using HTML5.
a small subset of google docs features TBH :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use OpenXML SDK. Its an awesome SDK tool by Microsoft. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb456488.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful: http://www.gelsheet.org/

It is an open source, web spreadsheet, that you can probably use.

Answer (score 0):

use http://crocodoc.com that may help. This is not open source but it does the thing.

Answer (score 0):

please try open source alternative for office 365:

- http://www.onlyoffice.org/sources#document  or  Broadway
- GDK-Backend http://www.golem.de/1108/85594.html or